# How to keep the screen lit in later versions of the kitkat API?

Tags: java, android, mobile

I am making an `APP` that keeps the smartphone screen lit, **even when the `APP` is minimized**.

I'm using a class with `extends Service` to do this, in `onCreate` I put the code that keeps the screen always lit:

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "watever");
    wl.acquire();
```

Android Studio gives me an alert: **FULL_WAKE_LOCK is deprecated**
But I have not figured out how to do it the current way.

This code is only working until **KitKat**.
In **Lollipop** or later, it does not show any error, but does not work.

The goal is to keep the screen lit even with the minimized `APP`.

This `APP`, for example, does this way: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.brilliant.apps.screenon

Answer (score 2):

> Most applications should use FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON instead of this type of wake lock, as it will be correctly managed by the platform as the user moves between applications and doesn't require a special permission.

Comment: How do i use it in the extends service class?  In the examples I've seen, it uses "getWindow ();" But this is not valid in the extends Service class.

Comment: @CristianCotrena, you should use it from activity, that needs to keep screen on.

Comment: I need to do using the "Service" to be able to use with the minimized APP. This APP, for example, does this way: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.brilliant.apps.screenon

Comment: In this way, I can minimize or close the APP that it keeps running.